# Interpreting AFT Model Coefficients: Mean vs. Median Survival Time in Log-Normal Distribution

Tags: survival, interpretation, lognormal-distribution, parametric, accelerated-failure-time

When interpreting the coefficients of an Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model that assumes a log-normal distribution, should we focus on the impact of coefficients on the mean survival time or the median survival time?

Comment: This depends on whether the mean or median survival time is more relevant for decisions with the model, and the question doesn’t provide enough context to determine that yet.